How to recognize different symbols in a picture with overlapping using CV/ML?
l have a picture with some information about the milestone of each project. Each milestone is marked in the diagram with unique symbol. In the picture we have different trianlges or squares with different colors.
l need to extract the informations about the dates from the symbols in legend. Which means l need to know the location of each symbol and its legend. Then search for the near dates in the x-axis and y-axis.
milestone picture
l have tried cv2 with color recognization. And first l have extracted the dates in the x-y-axis and save their postion. l use cv2 to the yellow rhombus and it works fine. But when it comes to red or grey, because there are different symbols but all in red. l cannot differenciate them just using cv2.
The traditional computer vision method in cv2 cannot deal with the overlapping. And there are for example two types of red triangles, one is pointing to the left. With all of these problems, l cannot find a good method to recognize each symbol in legend. Do you have any suggestions?
Maybe the ML to train is a potential solution. l have aroung 1000 of this kind of pictures. l dont know whether it is enough to train a model. But the workload will also be high.
l have also tried the template matching, but it does not work at all.
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('7053.jpg')
logo = cv2.imread('yellow.png')
height, width, _ = logo.shape

cv2.imshow('logo', logo)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

methods = [cv2.TM_CCOEFF, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED, cv2.TM_CCORR, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED, cv2.TM_SQDIFF, cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED]
titles = ['cv2.TM_CCOEFF', 'cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED', 'cv2.TM_CCORR', 'cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED', 'cv2.TM_SQDIFF', 'cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED']

for i in range(len(methods)):
    curImg = img.copy()
    method = methods[i]
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(img, logo, method)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

    if method in [cv2.TM_SQDIFF, cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED]:
        top_left = min_loc
    else:
        top_left = max_loc

    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + width, top_left[1] + height)
    cv2.rectangle(curImg, top_left, bottom_right, 255, 10)

    cv2.imshow('img', curImg)
    cv2.waitKey(0)


get the source data of this "milestone plan". do not operate on an illustration. -- all the symbol instances are pixel-exactly the same. use template matching. it will have trouble on the overlapping/occluded instances. you can handle that with nonzero tolerance. -- if you want to go the ML path, you can trivially generate synthetic data of these symbols, free-standing (pure background), occluded, or occluding others (background isn't pure).

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

l have no access to the source data. So l could only focus on the picture/illustration. l have tried the template matching after l saw your comment. Thanks. l have use the yellow rhombus as template and let cv2 search for it. But it does not work at all. (sad :( )

use any of the SQDIFF modes, not the other ones.
